# Greenstone Experience?

Tags: software, publishing

I'm looking for anyone that has a lot of back end experience with greenstone digital archival software.  This is mainly HTMl and CSS modifications.  It seems like a very small user base and their mailing list is terrible at best.

If anyone has ever worked with the backend part of this package or knows where I might be able to find some better information it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I work with Greenstone. What do you need?.
You can see some of the sites we developed here:

http://bibliotecadigital.innovacionagraria.cl/gsdl/cgi-bin/library.exe?l=es

http://bibliotecadigital.ciren.cl/gsdlexterna/cgi-bin/library.exe

Diego Spano
Prodigio Consultores
Capital Federal - Argentina
Tel: (54 11) 5093-5313

Comment: I need to know exactly how to set specific backgrounds for different collections.  I have my main one set in the style.dm file and I'm trying to set one in extra.dm for another collection but the one in style.dm seems to be the default choice.